# Set text color of all labels in a table view that has a bunch of static cells

Tags: swift, uitableview, static, uilabel, cell

I have a Settings screen that is a UITableViewController and contains round 20 static(!) cells (4 groups, 5 cells in each group). Every static cell contains a label.

Is there a way to set the text color of all labels without creating an outlet for each label and setting its text color individually?

Comment: They're grouped static cells?

Answer (score 3):

Here is one more way to do this. This one guarantees that you access all the labels in the cell's view hierarchy, does not matter at what level they are:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    recursiveSetTextColorForLabelsInView(cell)
}

func recursiveSetTextColorForLabelsInView(inView: UIView) {
    for view in inView.subviews {
        if let subview = view as? UILabel {
            subview.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
        }
        else {
            self.recursiveSetTextColorForLabelsInView(view)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively implement `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, just don't call `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` as that doesn't work on static tableView cells. Call `super.cellForRowAtIndexPath:` instead.

Then you can access the label via `cell.textLabel` or if custom cell: `cell.contentView.subviews.first as? UILabel`

Comment: Thank you, this seems to work but I ultimately went for a different way by accessing the label via `
- tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:`. See my own answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend subclassing UILabel, and setting your text color in the subclass. In your layout, change the class of your UILabels to your subclass. As a bonus, make it IBDesignable so you can see your customizations show up in the storyboard.

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class CustomLabel: UILabel {

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        customize()
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        customize()
    }

    private func customize() {
        textColor = UIColor.redColor()
    }

}
```

[image: Xcode]

Comment: Thank you. It is not bad but would be similar to assigning outlets to each label and setting it in `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` or in `- tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` seems cleaner and faster.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did it:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let view = cell.contentView.subviews.first
    if let viewToTest = view as? UILabel
    {
        viewToTest.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
    }
}
```

Actually in my case the label and other controls in a cell are in UIStackView, so to access the label view I use:

```
let view = cell.contentView.subviews.first?.subviews.first
```

instead of:

```
let view = cell.contentView.subviews.first
```

because in this case my labels are one level further in the cell.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I wanted to change an entire section's Alpha and userInteraction based on whether a switch is on of off. the answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/36097181/14414215 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/36100831/14414215 helped to steer in the right direction to this function.

```
 func updateCellAlpha() {
    let section = 1
    let numberOfRows = self.tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: section)
    
    for row in 0..<numberOfRows {
      if let cell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: row, section: section)) {
        for subview in cell.contentView.subviews {
          subview.alpha = syncToSwitch.isOn ? 1.0 : 0.5
          subview.isUserInteractionEnabled = syncToSwitch.isOn ? true : false
        }
      }
    }
  }
```